# Replace blank lines with specific text in Notepad ++

Tags: text, replace, notepad++

For example I have a text

```
Line1

Line3

Line5

Line6
```

And I need to replace the blank lines with a specific text, e.g. CoolText
so the result would be

```
Line1
CoolText
Line3
CoolText
Line5
CoolText
Line6
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: I am not trying to remove the blank lines, I am trying to replace the blank lines with a specific text. Finding \r\n and replacing with CoolText does not accomplish this task, it only places CoolText at the end of each line and deletes the blank lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the extended replacement feature in NotePad++. Search for doubled carriage return/line feed pairs (`\r\n\r\n`), and replace them with a carriage return/line feed pair, the replacement text, and another CR/LF pair (`\r\nCoolText\r\n`).

Here's the text file with the dialog set up for the replacement, before clicking "Replace All":

[image: NPP Before Replace Image]

Here are the results after clicking "Replace All":

[image]

Comment: In case you have 2 and more empty lines one after another, you need to press "Replace All" button a few more times =)